# choicetype wrongly recognized in Symfony3

Tags: php, twig, symfony

I have the data array like below,

`$cityLists = array('1' => 'Washington', '2' => 'London', '3' => 'Chennai');`

In the buildForm method I pass the data as,

`$builder->add('cityId', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => $cityLists,
            'empty_data'  => null))`

In the rendered twig form the dropdown values are displayed in opposite(ie, the options behind the dropdowns are Washington, London, Chennai and the corresponding displayed values are 1, 2, 3) but it was correctly displayed with symfony 2.7.
Do you see anything wrong in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ChoiceType is refactored in Symfony 2.7 and now expects key/value to be switched. In Symfony 2.x, the old behaviour still worked in order to be backwards compatible.

While upgrading, especially a major version upgrade, make sure you read all UPGRADE guides and update your code. If you upgrade to the latest 2.x first (2.8), you'll get a change to have a working app and see all deprecation notices (which often also include solutions), before upgrading everything to Symfony 3.

In this case, the change is perfectly documented in [UPGRADE-2.7.md](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.7.md).

Comment: Thanks for the details and link. I haven't really looked at it.